# A possible error in the inductive proof of $2k+1<2^k$ for $k\ge 3$

Tags: inequality, induction

[image]

This is the answer to a basic induction problem. I feel that that the author may have made a typo...

$2^k + 2^k = 2^k \cdot 2^1  = 2^{k+1}$

Comment: Why do you think it's an error?

Comment: Why do you feel this is a typo? There is no error here. What do you think should be written instead?

Comment: edited my answer, the 2^(k+1) is not equivalent to  2^k+ 2^1.

Comment: I see no where the author asserts that.

Comment: Ahh typo on my part on my comment. Sorry chou. Are the 2 highlighted texts equivilent is what I'm asking.

Comment: The highlighted parts are *not* equivalent, but this is no mistake. Either one is greater than $2(k+1)+1$. This is exploited by the author in his or her proof.

Comment: ahh okay makes sense now.:)

Answer (score 4):

No, that is not a typo. What the author is saying is that since, by the assumption that $2k + 1 < 2^k$, one can substitute $2^k$ for $2k + 1$ in the equality $2k + 1 + 2 = 2(k + 1) + 1$ to find the inequality $2(k+1) + 1 < 2^k + 2$. Since $2^k + 2 < 2^k + 2^k = 2^{k+1}$, this inequality implies what you want to show.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps the following will make it easier for you to understand.

---

**First, show that this is true for $k=3$:**

$2\cdot3+1<2^3$

**Second, assume that this is true for $k$:**

$2k+1<2^k$

**Third, prove that this is true for $k+1$:**

$2(k+1)+1=$

$2k+3=$

$\color\red{2k+1}+2<$

$\color\red{2^k}+2=$

$2^k+\color\green{2^1}<$

$2^k+\color\green{2^k}=$

$2^{k+1}$

---

Please note that the assumption is used only in the part marked red.